# How Can add next and previous button to Fancybox

Tags: fancybox

I have a small code as shows below, I want to add previous and next button when  pictures popup.

https://www.jqueryscript.net/gallery/Simple-Clean-jQuery-Vertical-Product-Gallery.html

Comment: It would be better to post your code you are using along your question and describe what you have tried, otherwise your question can be flagged, downvoted, eventually deleted and worse, never answered